# What Open Source (command line/API) method is there to orthorectify and georeference an aerial image given telemetry data?

Tags: raster, gdal, osgeo, photogrammetry, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

How can I take an image and orthorectify it automatically with open source software?
The information associated with each image is:

- camera specs
- latitude, longitude, elevation of the camera
- orientation of the camera: facing down off a UAV, roll pitch and yaw are given

I want to output a geotiff file and hopefully end up stitching the images together to create a map.

Comment: Maybe the GRASS module i.ortho.photo can help?

Answer (score 3):

Open Aerial Map's wiki (http://openaerialmap.org/Processing) suggests

- GRASS GIS' [i.ortho.photo](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.ortho.photo.html) and related modules (per Micha's suggestion).
- OSSIM http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/ - probably best bet.
- http://www.digilab.uni-hannover.de/index.html - looks like it would require some development work to be useful
- http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/ - very active development, but perhaps more suited to satellite than UAV.

Comment: I'm looking to do this as well. Does anyone have a modern guide on OSSIM?

Answer (score 2):

this [link](http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/palentier-using-uav-open) describes the use of the open source software [Palentier](http://www.palentier.com/) , but i don't know the accuracy supported with this suite, and if it could produce DEM or just stitched photos.

i think the [point cloud library](http://pointclouds.org/) could help too.

Answer (score 0):

man check out http://opendronemap.github.io/odm/. this is an old question but it seems like these guys have a really workable piece of software now, i have not personally tried it yet but it looks good.

Here is a link to a youtube video of it in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2qp3o8caPs